# Persisting special characters in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, special-characters

I have an Object

```
Grinding modelObj = new Grinding();             
modelObj.setGrinding_name("Allégé");
```

I want to persist this object in Google app engine datastore. When i try to save the object as given below:

```
DatastoreService DS ... 
Key temp = DS.put(getEntity(modelObj));
```

Its getting stored as " All�g�". Any resolution??

Comment: try encoding and decoding. you can store the base64 encoded value and when you will retieve decode it as base 64. I think app engine encodes it for security and injection

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the Datastore - I use it to store texts in many different languages with no problems. You need to set the encoding to UTF-8 when you send data from the client to your App Engine instance.

For example, I use REST, so I set the following headers on my requests:

```
requestBuilder.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

and responses:

```
resp.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: I am not sending the value from the client. Its a constant value and the value is set to the object directly and persisted. So even if i encode request and response, no difference.

Comment: Make sure your Eclipse settings are set to UTF-8.